# Rotation step motor arduino

Tags: arduino, motordriver

I have an Arduino and a step motor, this is my code :

```
#include <Stepper.h>

// Définir le nombre de pas par tour
int NbrPas = 200; 


Stepper MonMoteur(NbrPas, 8, 9, 10, 11);

void setup() {
  // Vitesse à 60 tours/min
  MonMoteur.setSpeed(60);
 
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // Faire un tour dans un sens
  Serial.println("Sens 1");
  MonMoteur.step(NbrPas);
  delay(500);
}
```

It's for 1 round, I would like to know how to make several rounds with my step motor

Comment: What do you mean more than one round? Per loop? If that is what you meant, just change NbrPas to a higher value

Comment: Please notice that you are setting the speed to 60rpm (that's 1 revolution per second) but then you are asking the motor to turn 1 full revolution only allowing 500ms for that to happen. You should be careful about that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make several rounds, firstly you have to change the value of ***NbrPas*** setting the number of steps per revolution suited to your needs.
In your case you must set `int NbrPas = 2048;`.

Another piece of advice I can give you is to put an adequate value to `MonMoteur.setSpeed();`. In *28BYJ-48 stepper motors* the range is 0~17 rpm.

---

I think this code is fine for your case

```
#include <Stepper.h>

const int NbrPas = 2048;  // change this to fit the number of steps per revolution
const int rolePerMinute = 15;         // Adjustable range of 28BYJ-48 stepper is 0~17 rpm

Stepper MonMoteur(NbrPas, 8, 9, 10, 11);

void setup() {
  // Vitesse à 60 tours/min
  MonMoteur.setSpeed(rolePerMinute);
 
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // Faire un tour dans un sens
  Serial.println("Sens 1");
  makeOneRound();
  delay(500);
}


void makeOneRound() {
  MonMoteur.step(NbrPas);
}
```